# Getting top urls from an IP address from a nginx log file

Tags: linux, nginx, logging, awk

I'm after some assistance in getting some stats from an nginx log file.  Something is hammering our site and I can see the top ip from this awk command:

```
sudo awk '{ print $1}' /var/log/nginx/access.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 50
```

I need to be able to get a list of the urls from this top ip?  Can anyone help with the best way to acheive this?

I've got the awk command to lisst the top urls here but need to put them together:

```
sudo awk '{ print $7}' /var/log/nginx/access.log| sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 20
```

Thanks

John

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo awk '{print $1}' /var/log/nginx/access.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The OP needs to get all URLs (column #7) from the logs only for the top IPs, which is the answer you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
logfile="/var/log/nginx/access.log"
grep "^$(cat "${logfile}" | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 1 | awk -F' ' '{print $2}') " "${logfile}" | cut -d' ' -f7 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 50
```